# Unable to implement DatePickerDialog on Android

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#implement-an-ontimesetlistenerondatesetlistener), and I'm following what it says.

I've added this implementation to my class:

`implements com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`

And this method:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/"+year;
}
```

But for some reason I get the error:

> Class 'xxxx' must be either declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onDateSet(..)

I've also seen the sample, and I've done the same thing it does there.

Comment: I would guess that the `DatePickerDialog` parameter type for your `onDateSet()` method is the wrong one. It should probably be `com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog`, not `android.app.DatePickerDialog`, which is probably what you have imported. You could use the fully-qualified class name there, or change your `import` statement.

Comment: @MikeM. You're a Legend. Post this as the answer so I can mark it and help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an error message like that, but you've already got a method with the given name, it usually means that the signature is wrong. In this case, it's pretty much gotta be that the `DatePickerDialog` type for the first parameter is the wrong one, since `int`s are `int`s everywhere.

If your IDE auto-imported a `DatePickerDialog` class, it probably chose `android.app.DatePickerDialog`. That interface, though, is expecting `com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog`. You can either use the fully-qualified class name in the method signature, or just change your `import` statement to point to the correct class.